# OnApplyTemplate method does not get called when the custom control is being rendered

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, custom-controls

I have made a custom control for windows phone 7.

If I use this control in XAML code, it shows up in both the designer and the emulator.

But if I create in C# code and render it in a WriteableBitmap, nothing shows up in the WriteableBitmap, and the OnApplyTemplate does not get called either.

I tried calling the ApplyTemplate method and the Measure and Arrange methods, but none of them can make the control to be rendered.

So what is the right approach to make a custom control renderable in a WriteableBitmap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before a WPF template is applied, which includes Silverlight, an object must be added to a visual tree.  Calling ApplyTemplate will simply fail if the object isn't in a visual tree.  So to make it render properly, add it to a visual tree, then you can call ApplyTemplate / UpdateLayout / etc. and have it render correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but we I need to do is to render it to a bitmap without showing it in the main page. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: And I just found out that we can render a text block to a bitmap without adding it to a visual tree, and also the subclasses of Shape.

Comment: You can render anything that doesn't have a template without adding to visual tree.  As for custom controls, you do not have to show them visibly.  You can create a window that you don't ever make visible, add it as a child of that, render it, and let the window get garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think we can afford to do that, because we are rendering a big amount of that custom control.

Comment: Don't let the window get garbage collected then.  Keep it around and add each control to it as its child, then remove the child once rendered.  That way it won't affect your performance.